# Where I can find samples C# project for Outlook add in for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I can find samples which are created for VS 2005 and that are not running under vs2010.
Can I find some sample outlook add in projectes for VS2010 using C#.

Comment: Sorry, when did StackOverflow become a search service?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx).